# Why does the Excel formula substitute not work for me?

Tags: excel, string-concatenation, substitution, textjoin

Sorry... I had originally posted this as an answer :-)

I have a spreadsheet that uses various formulas. When I get to some of the lists, some containing 16 items, I am concatenating 16 different cells, each resulting from an Excel "if" formula. For example, if a cell = 1, then a certain cell is selected that contains the name of an activity, if that same cell = 0, then another cell containing "'" is the result (so that the cell is "empty". All these various cells are then concatenated. Later, I can put this list within a sentence. Using the above "=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,A1:A14),", "," and ",MAX(1,COUNTA(A1:A14)-1))", I was able to get rid of the extra commas, which was very helpful! However, the "and" part of the formula does not work for me.... unless I have it select cells with words typed into them and I leave some blank.

Tried the "=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,A1:A14),", "," and ",MAX(1,COUNTA(A1:A14)-1))" and substituted my 16 selected cells for the range. I also arranged my various 16 cells in a column with the same result.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are trying to do. Put simply, `and` is not something you can use it in a formula in they way you are using it here. What is the purpose of your `and` in this formula.

Comment: @topsail it's perfectly clear: join a range as a comma separated string, then replace the last comma with " and "

Comment: Oh I see. I thought the and was not inside quotes :( My bad!

Answer (score 0):

You say *... then another cell containing "'" is the result (so that the cell is "empty"*

The problem is with `COUNTA(A1:A14)`.  That is counting all the cells, because a cell containing a formula that returns an exmpty string is not actually empty, so it gets counted.

What you want is to count the number of commers (or number of strings -1).

This will give you that count `SUM(--(LEN(A1:A14)>0))-1))`

Used like this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,A1:A14),", "," and ",MAX(1,SUM(--(LEN(A1:A14)>0))-1))
```

---

From your comment it seems you are trying to apply this to a non-contiguous range.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,AT275,AT277,AT279,AT281,AT283,AT285,AT287,AT289,AT290,BA275,BA277,BA279,BA281,BA283,BA285,BA287),", "," and ",MAX(1,SUM(--(LEN(AT275,AT277,AT279,AT281,AT283,AT285,AT287,AT289,AT290,BA275,BA277,BA279,BA281,BA283,BA285,BA287)>0))-1))
```

The reason that fails and my answer works is that `LEN` does not work with non-contiguous ranges.

If you have Excel 365 you can convert the non-contiguous into a contiguous range using `VSTACK`. (And use LET to avoid repeating the range)

```
=LET(txt,VSTACK(AS275,AS277,AS279,AS281,AS283,AS285,AS287,AS289,AS290,AZ275,AZ277,AZ279,AZ281,AZ283,AZ285,AZ287),  
  Last, MAX(1, SUM(--(LEN(txt)>0))-1),
  SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,txt),", "," and ",Last))
```

An alternative is to find the position of the last `,` in the joined string

```
=LET(txt,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,AS275,AS277,AS279,AS281,AS283,AS285,AS287,AS289,AS290,AZ275,AZ277,AZ279,AZ281,AZ283,AZ285,AZ287), 
  Last,LEN(txt)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(txt,",","")),
  SUBSTITUTE(txt,","," and",Last))
```

Comment: " and " still does not show up :-(

Comment: I have 16 items (activities) with checkboxes. For each, when the check box next to each item is checked, it turns a corresponding cell (#1) from false to true. The cell (#2) next to cell #1 has a corresponding "if" formula: if cell #1 is true then (activity), if cell #1 is false then "'" (so the cell is blank). I am then concatenating those16 different #2 resulting cells of activities. I want ending activity to have the word "and" before it so it makes sense when I concatenate it into another sentence. Hope that is clearer?

Comment: This is the formula I have typed in as these are all of the cells I am pulling from: =SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,AT275,AT277,AT279,AT281,AT283,AT285,AT287,AT289,AT290,BA275,BA277,BA279,BA281,BA283,BA285,BA287),", "," and ",MAX(1,SUM(--(LEN(AT275,AT277,AT279,AT281,AT283,AT285,AT287,AT289,AT290,BA275,BA277,BA279,BA281,BA283,BA285,BA287)>0))-1))

Do you see a problem with it?